# LLVM - given a register, get where it was last used in the IR representation

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, dataflow

I am trying to keep track of data flow in my source code. For that, I'm looking at instructions of type `load` and obtaining which register they're loading the value from with the use of

```
*(LI->getPointerOperand())
```

`LI` being the instruction of type `LoadInst`. Now I need to know where this register was last accessed so that I can point that check the data flow from that instruction to this one. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "last accessed" in a static analysis context? Do you mean something like (to put it very simply) the closest previous access in the control flow graph?

Comment: Yes. That is what I mean. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, simplify the problem by excluding loops and functions with multiple exits, so that you have a function CFG as a single entry and single exit graph.

One (probably simplistic) way would be to first find all its users by doing something like:

```
llvm::Instruction i = [the register for that LoadInst];
auto users = i->users();
```

Then using the [`PostDominatorTree`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/structllvm_1_1PostDominatorTree.html) and the `getLevel` method of the [`DomTreeNodeBase`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DomTreeNodeBase.html) (I think [this](https://reviews.llvm.org/D34548?id=104930) was introduced with `LLVM` 5.0.0, if not available in your version you could use `getChildren` and perform a [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) traversal), you could filter through those with the highest level number.

I'm not sure what you want to do with loops, but if nothing special, the above should suffice. For dealing with multiple exits from functions you could make use of the [`mergereturn`](https://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#mergereturn-unify-function-exit-nodes) pass prior to any processing.